# How to select data within MySql column with X characters?

Tags: mysql

How do I select rows within a column where the string length equals 5 characters?

I am aware of length() and char_length() functions, but they seem to only be for sorting of data query results.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(yourcolumn)=5`. Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Still struggling? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(yourcolumn)=5